# Javascript compare key of dictionary in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I've got two arrays with dictionaries like this:

```
var arr1 = [
    {id: 1, key1: "hello", key2: "world"},
    {id: 2, key1: "some", key2: "value"},
    {id: 3, key1: "...", key2: "..."}
]
var arr2 = [
    {id: 2, key1: "new", key2: "val"},
    {id: 5, key1: "...", key2: "..."}
]
```

I'd like to create a loop which takes all values of the `arr1`, but takes the value of `arr2` if the id exists there. The result would look like this:

```
var result = [
    {id: 1, key1: "hello", key2: "world"},
    {id: 2, key1: "new", key2: "val"},
    {id: 3, key1: "...", key2: "..."}
]
```

I've tried it with the following loop, which should check if the `arr2` contains the id of the current Object in `arr1`. This is working, when there's only 1 entry in my arrays with a matching id. But when there are 2+ matches it's not working anymore.

```
var result = []
arr1.map(val1 => {
    arr2.some(val2 => {
        val2.id === val1.id ? result.push(val2) : result.push(val1)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with this one-liner that uses [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var arr1 = [
    { id: 1, key1: "hello", key2: "world" },
    { id: 2, key1: "some", key2: "value" },
    { id: 3, key1: "...", key2: "..." }
];

var arr2 = [
    { id: 2, key1: "new", key2: "val" },
    { id: 5, key1: "...", key2: "..." }
];

const result = arr1.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, arr2.find(({ id }) => cur.id === id) || cur], []);

console.log(result);
```